# ClassCastException: with unnamed module of loader 'app': Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classcastexception, spring-data-redis

I am working on a small demo project for **Redis and Spring Boot.** But for the following **GET** endpoints I am getting **ClassCastException.**-

```
@GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public Product finProduct(@PathVariable int id){
        return productRepository.findProductById(id);
    }
```

Serivces-

```
public List<Product> findAll() {
        List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();
        redisTemplate.opsForHash().values(HASH_KEY).forEach(e->products.add((Product)e));
        return products;
    }

    public Product findProductById(int id) {

        return (Product) redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(HASH_KEY, id);
    }
```

I am getting following error-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ayushsingh.springdataredisdemo.entity.Product cannot be cast to class com.ayushsingh.springdataredisdemo.entity.Product (com.ayushsingh.springdataredisdemo.entity.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.ayushsingh.springdataredisdemo.entity.Product is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @18f69edd)
```

I referred the following article: https://medium.com/javarevisited/classcast-exception-when-using-redis-and-springboot-frameworks-in-conjunction-ea132dd0d7ea, but still getting same error.
**Beans-**

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

    // Connection Configuration
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName("localhost");
        configuration.setPort(6379);
        Duration readTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(30 * 1000);
        Duration connectTimeout = Duration.ofMillis(3 * 1000);
        JedisClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder()
                .readTimeout(readTimeout)
                .connectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                .usePooling()
                .build();
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration, clientConfiguration);
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    // Redis template to acces Redis server
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader()));
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader()));
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);

        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```

**application properties-**

```
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false
server.port=8082
```

Please help!

Comment: Seems to be an issue with ClassLoader. Could you try removing one or the other in         template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader()));
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader()));

Comment: I tried-  template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader())); and the other way template.setHashKeySerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(getClass().getClassLoader()));
        template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer()); but getting the same error.

Comment: This is almost certainly related to devtools, you could try removing the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency entirely to see if that "fixes" things.

Comment: I removed devtools and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I met the same error. The only way is to remove `spring-devtools` module. It seems like to be caused by `ClassLoader`. But I don't know how to solve it. But removing this module really worked.

Comment: But how is disabling spring-devtools resolving this issue? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: I didn't dive into this problem. Maybe the spring devtools module use different ClassLoader than Jeddis (many Spring projects use Jeddis to interact with Redis). This causes Jeddis can't wrapper response to object in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

> you need to set a System property before calling SpringApplication.run(…​). For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);}
```

Reference [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring devtools.Disabled devtools it will work.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Please explain exactly what to do for your suggestion to work.