# Spring boot ClassCastException to Jackson

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, jackson

I make simple Spring Boot app with MongoDB and face that issue in my controller class:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController'
>
> > Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.pypek.testtaskapi.controller.UserController]: Constructor threw exception
> >
> > > Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@5f4d427e' with class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' to class 'com.pypek.testtaskapi.service.UserService'
> > > 2023-10-27T18:25:15.334876863Z  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:424) ~[groovy-4.0.15.jar!/:4.0.15]
> > > 2023-10-27T18:25:15.334879707Z  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:335) ~[groovy-4.0.15.jar!/:4.0.15]
> > > 2023-10-27T18:25:15.334882393Z  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:255) ~[groovy-4.0.15.jar!/:4.0.15]
> > > 2023-10-27T18:25:15.335049101Z  at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v8.IndyInterface.fromCache(IndyInterface.java:321) ~[groovy-4.0.15.jar!/:4.0.15]

My code controller:

```
package com.pypek.testtaskapi.controller

import com.pypek.testtaskapi.model.User
import com.pypek.testtaskapi.service.UserService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
class UserController {

@Autowired
UserService service

UserController(UserService service) {
    this.service = service
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
def getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
    return service.getUser(id)
}

@PatchMapping
def updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    service.updateUser(user)
}

@PostMapping
def addUser(@RequestBody User user){
    service.addUser(user)
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
def deleteUser(@PathVariable String id){
    service.deleteUser(id)
}
}
```

Service:

```
package com.pypek.testtaskapi.service

import com.pypek.testtaskapi.exceptions.UserNotFoundExceptions
import com.pypek.testtaskapi.model.User
import com.pypek.testtaskapi.repository.UserRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class UserService {

    UserRepository repository

    @Autowired
    UserService(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository
    }

    def getUser(String id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundExceptions(id))
    }

    String addUser(User user) {
        return repository.save(user).getId()
    }

    def updateUser(User user) {
        def id = user.getId()
        if (checkIfUserExist(id)){
            return repository.save(user)
        } else throw new UserNotFoundExceptions(id)
    }

    def deleteUser(String id) {
        if (checkIfUserExist(id)) {
            repository.deleteById(id)
        } else throw new UserNotFoundExceptions(id)
    }

    def checkIfUserExist(String id) {
        return repository.existsById(id)
    }
}
```

Any idea why Spring boot try convert that???

Answer (score 0):

Just remove from you dependency list 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'. Thanks guys from [ClassCastException: with unnamed module of loader 'app': Spring Data Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943457/classcastexception-with-unnamed-module-of-loader-app-spring-data-redis)